# Form Data Submit into jquery pop-up div display same page after get the post & get request

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have created a form. There are the following inputs:

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type='text' name='first_name' />
  <input type='text' name='last_name' />
  <input type='text' name='email' />
  <input type='text' name='phone' />
  <input type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

I want to submit the above form within a jQuery pop-up in a stylish manner just like light-box jQuery by using a POST request in the same file like index.html. From there I'd like to load a different file in a pop-up which will post the values of form like inquiry.php.

If it is possible then please update step by step tutorial for this topic. I have already searched but I am not finding suitable topics about it.

Comment: `update step by step tutorial for this topic` we are not a freelancers.post your tried code

Comment: Did u try something?post fiddle

Comment: I have tried this method but it is open in new windows tap. i want to open it new div light box..... $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
        this.target = 'formpopup';
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div id="pop-up">
<form method="post" id="myform">
<input type='text' name='first_name' />
<input type='text' name='last_name' />
<input type='text' name='email' />
<input type='text' name='phone' />
<input type='button' value='submit' id='send'/>
</form>
</div>
```

js on page (jquery):

```
(function($) {
   $('#send').click(function(){
      $.post('inquiry.php', 
         $('#myform').serialize())
      .done(function(data) {
          $('#pop-up').html(data);
      });
   });
})(jQuery);
```

inquiry.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST['first_name'] . ' ' . $_POST['second_name'];
//...
```

Comment: @user3340947 not at all. please, if it helps, approve answer)